# Bijection between $(0,1)$ and the set of infinite binary sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I have been searching this problem in the internet for a while but I am still unable to get around the infinite 0's and 1's problem.

So far I have gathered some information. Please correct me if I am wrong:

1. $\forall x\in (0,1)$, there exists decimal and binary expression.
2. $\forall x\in (0,1)$, the expansion are in 4 forms: repeating, non-repeating, infinite 0's and 1's
3. Schroder-Bernstein theorem which states two injections between two sets implies same cardinality between the two sets

However, I still can't establish an bijection between $(0,1)$ and the set of infinite binary strings. Is it possible to show how?

Comment: if I get correctly the question, you basically want to show that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ has the same cardinality as $(0,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number in $(0,1)\setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left\{ \frac{k}{2^n}: \ k=1,2,\ldots 2^{n-1} \right\}$ has unique binary expansion. The set $A:= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left\{ \frac{k}{2^n}: \ k=1,2,\ldots 2^{n-1} \right\}$ is countable as a countable union of finite sets.

Now every number of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, has two expansions one of them ends with infinite zros (for example $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{0}{2^i} = 0 + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i}$). Furthermore, if a binary expansion of an $x$ ends with infinite zeros then $x$ clearly is in $A$. **($\ast$)**

Also if $(x_1, x_2, \ldots ) \in \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$, then $x:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{2^i} \in (0,1)$. **($\ast \ast$)**

So define $h:\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \to (0,1)$ by $h((x_1, x_2, \ldots ))=x:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{2^i} \in (0,1)$

Then $h$ is onto and thus $|\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}| \geq |(0,1)|$. In particular $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.

Now set $B\subset \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the set of the sequences that end with infinite zeros, i.e. the set the binary expansions of each $x\in A$ such that it ends with infinite zeros.

Observe that the restriction  $h: \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus B \to (0,1) $ is, by **($\ast$)** and **($\ast \ast$)**, a bijection.
Thus $|\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus \{1^n0^{\infty}: \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}| = |(0,1)|$

Also $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} = \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus B \ \dot\bigcup \ B$, disjoint union, and the last set is countable.
Hence, $|\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}| = |\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus B| = |(0,1)|$

Comment: There are other numbers with two binary expansions (any $k/2^n$, not just with $k=1$; basically all terminating expansions have a non-terminating alternative), but they are countable.

Comment: you are completely right. I'll edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and sorry for my tardiness. I have 2 follow-up questions. I may predicate on wrong understandings. Please correct me if I am wrong. 1. $B$ is countable and $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} = \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus B \ \dot\bigcup \ B$ is uncountable. I understand this part. But what is the leap from here to $|\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}| = |\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus B|$? 2. Is set A referring to the set of real numbers with infinite ending zeros? If yes, does it miss something say $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$ which isn't in the form of $\frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: $A$ is the subset of $(0,1)$ such that it contains numbers of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$ (as $\frac{3}{4}$ is for example). $B$ is the set containing the (one out of two) expansions of such numbers, namely the one expansion of each number of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$ that ends in infinite zeros. Now, for the other question, let $C$ be an uncountable set and $D\subset C$ be countable. If $|C \setminus D| < |C|$ then $|C|= |C\setminus D| + |D| < |C|$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @alphaomega Thanks for the reply! 1. So I guess I am wrong. I thought $k$ is $2^0, 2^1\cdots 2^{n-1}$. It seems that it is simply natural numbers from 1 to $2^{n-1}$; 2. I am not so good with cardinality. If my understand is right, by contradiction, $|C \setminus D|\geq |C|$ and suppose $|C \setminus D|>|C|$, then $|C|-|D|<|C|$ and $|D|<0$, which contradicts D is nonempty! Hence $|C\setminus D|=|C|$. Right?

Comment: Yes $k\in \{ 1,2, \ldots , 2^{n-1} \}$. So in general, if $Y\subset X|$, the $|Y|\leq |X|$ i.e. either $|Y|= |X|$ or $|Y|< |X|$ . Now if $X=C$ and $Y=D$ is as in my previous comment, i.e. $C$ is uncountable and $D\subset C$ is countable , then the assumption that $|D| < |D\setminus C|$ leads to a contradiction.